# View another schemas objects in object explorer . SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to see the objects from another schema that I have read permissions from in the object explorer. I can select from them in the query window but I do not see them in the object explorer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have read permissions, they will be in Object Explorer.

The sorting is schema.objectname.

If you still don't see them, try closing and reopening SSMS because it does cache information.

If still not visible, you don't have permissions says [Metadata Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The newlogin hasthe db_reader role. 
I have granted the user select and view definition permisssions from the other schema as well.
Closed and reopenend and reconnected using the new login and still am not able to see the objects from the other user.
I can see them in the query window srop down while typing the select statement however.
Please help.